# Adding custom field in menu options

Tags: functions, custom-field, menus, forms

Please take a look at this image
[image]

Is there's anyway I can add another field called "Font Awesome Icon" for the user to write the icon class and the output should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome-4-menus/

which does exactly what you need.

Go to your **Screen Options** panel (top right) and activate **CSS Classes**. Then add `fa-home fa-fw` to your CSS class field.

Comment: Okay but the output will just add the class to the "li" tag, I need the output like what I mentioned before in the question.

Comment: Isn't there a way to rewrite your menu to accept CSS classes?

Comment: See if this link helps: http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/